# SQL select count two conditions

Tags: mysql

I am working on an online form. Before a user fills in this form, he is asked to select the type of form and the year of the form. These values are placed in $formType and $year respectively.

I would like to prevent a user from submitting the same form twice ie if user attempts to submit form A for year 2011, and there already exists one in the database, then he is prevented from doing so.

Thus i need a SELECT COUNT function with two conditions, obtained from php variables.
So far, I have managed to do this in SQL but only when using one condition, as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(`formType`)
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `formType` = '$formType' ;
```

However, when i tried to filter both conditions, it didn't work. The code is below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'year', 'formType' 
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `year` = '$year' AND 'formType' = '$formType')
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated

Comment: Does this works: `SELECT count(*)
    FROM table1
    WHERE year = '$year' AND formType = '$formType'` ?

Comment: no sorry. If i use one of the conditions then it works, but not for both at the same time.

Comment: What is result of this? any error or wrong count?

Comment: for one condition it works perfectly i.e if i leave the condition for year, and i already have a form with year = 2007, then when i attempt to enter a form with year also = 2007, i am not allowed to do so. the same thing happens if i use the form type condition.

Comment: My question is: *Why giving 2 conditions doesn't work for you?* Do you get **any error** if you provide 2 conditions? or Do you get **wrong count** when you provide 2 conditions?

Comment: Hi,
i solved it. Thanks for your responses.
the error i get is that when i attempt to enter a form with formType=A and year=2007, and i know that i already have a form in my database with formType=A and year=2007, the form is still submitted.
When i used a single condition, ie was only checking year, then the form was not submitted hence the code was working.
Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need a subquery? Following should do

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `table1`
    WHERE `year` = '$year' AND `formType` = '$formType'
```

You probably want to allow one formtype per year **per user**, so you want to add third condition into query, something like `AND userID = xx` (unless you have one table per user).

Comment: Hi,
thanks this worked. However i had attempted this earlier and it had not worked before. 
The reason it seems that i was typing 'formType' instead of ` formType `, and that's why it wasn't working.

Comment: @darryl schembri - if this answers your question, the nice thing to do is mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'or' instead of 'and'

```
select count (*) 
from table1
where (year = $year) or (formtype = $formtype)
```

Comment: As I understand it, the OP wants to allow one formtype per year, using `OR` would be wrong.

Comment: @Ain: That might be so now, but wasn't clear when the question was first posted. A common beginner's mistake is to use 'and' when they mean 'or'.